# Primer proyecto en Arduino y tengo este error:

Tags: arduino

[image: ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo? (la placa es un arduino uno)]
Estoy tratando de realizar mi primer proyecto en arduino, es un "tacho de basura smart",
busque en algunos foros y dicen que podría ser un tema del usb o que la placa este dañada, pero la placa es nueva, la adquirí hoy.
(Disculpen si el problema es algo tonto, soy nuevo en esto,muchas gracias por sus respuestas!)

El código que estoy usando es :

```
#include <Servo.h>   //servo library
Servo servo;     
int trigPin = 5;    
int echoPin = 6;   
int servoPin = 7;
int led= 10;
long duration, dist, average;   
long aver[3];   //array for average


void setup() {       
    Serial.begin(9600);
    servo.attach(servoPin);  
    pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);  
    pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);  
    servo.write(0);         //close cap on power on
    delay(100);
    servo.detach(); 
} 

void measure() {  
 digitalWrite(10,HIGH);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(5);
digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(15);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
dist = (duration/2) / 29.1;    //obtain distance
}
void loop() { 
  for (int i=0;i<=2;i++) {   //average distance
    measure();               
   aver[i]=dist;            
    delay(10);              //delay between measurements
  }
 dist=(aver[0]+aver[1]+aver[2])/3;    

if ( dist<50 ) {
//Change distance as per your need
 servo.attach(servoPin);
  delay(1);
 servo.write(0);  
 delay(3000);       
 servo.write(150);    
 delay(1000);
 servo.detach();      
}
Serial.print(dist);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes.

Para eso suele haber tres causas diferentes:

- Hay cable conectado al pin 0
- Está seleccionado el puerto COM incorrecto (el IDE no ve la board que programa el Arduino). Revisa el Device manager, a ver dónde está conectada la board y luego confirma que el IDE le apunta al mismo puerto COM.
  De paso revisa que tienes configurado el modelo de board correcto.
- Los drivers Arduino no están montados correctamente. El device Manager en el sistema operativo debería mostrar la board
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias! ya se soluciono, como dijiste , tenia el puerto COM incorrecto!

Comment: Súper! Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada para que otros la usen cuando tengan el mismo problema